# Prevent TabHost Tab Change?

Tags: android

Is there any way with the stock Android TabHost to prevent a tab change from taking place ???

In iOS, there is a delegate callback called shouldSelectViewController on the tabBarController, which if you return FALSE prevents the tab change from taking place.

Android has an onTabChanged() delegate, but that appears to be an after-the-fact notification that the tab change has taken place (it returns void).

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use onTabChanged() for that, you can set OnClickListener/OnTouchListener for each tab and do it there. Example:

```
    for(int i=0; i<tabWidget.getTabCount(); i++) {
        tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {                      
                    String currentTabTag = (String) tabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
                    String clickedTabTag = (String) v.getTag();

                    if(clickedTabTag.equals("BAD TAG")) {
                        return true; // Prevents from clicking
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }               
        });
    }
```

Comment: Two notes - You need to specify a tag because "v" does not refer to the tabSpec created, it's the layout in the view. Also @override must be declared.  After all that this does not work because the tab control has already colored the new tab orange and it looks terrible. Even invalidating it does not help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent the tab from changing, for example you always want the tab be tab 0, try this code:

```
if (tabId.equals("Tab 1")) {
   // This will switch tab 1 to tab 0 immediately so that it seems like tab 0 does not change
  getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);
}
```