# Android how make tabhost's tab behaves as a button

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I'd like to creat a tabhost's tab which behaves as a Button to display a Dialog

Here is my current code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);

            mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost
            .newTabSpec("Critères")
            .setIndicator(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button_tabs_bg, null)),
            MyDialogFragment.class, null);

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost
            .newTabSpec("Map")
            .setIndicator("Map"),
            MyMapFragment.class, null);
        }   
}
```

As you can see I set the tab's content to look like a button but it is not what I expect for.
I juste want a normal tab which display a Dialog without be selected.

Do you have any ideas how to proceed ?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add on tab changed listener to your tabhost

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // build dialog and show
        }
    }
});
```

According to your additional request. You have to options:

1. Extend Tabhost class and override setCurrentTab method - this way you may stop execution of new fragment.
2. Add onClick / ouTouch listener for each tab seperate and stop on the unwanted one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192064/503127

Comment: It works but the tabhost almost do what he expected to. I can just add things. Is there an other way ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little? What does "tabhost almost do what he expected to" mean?

Comment: The tabhost's property is to replace a fragment by an other when pressing tabs. Your solution helped me to add a behaviour like displaying a dialog box. But I want forbid tabhost to replace the actual fragment when pressing.

Comment: Ok thank you. I progressed. When tab button is pressed I setCurrentTab to an other. It works well but I'd like to know the tab which I come from. His there a method or should I found a trick ?

Comment: A trick is to store last tab `id` as a variable (in activity scope) and change it in onTabChange listener :)

Comment: I was thinking about it ^^ thanks a lot for your help and your patience! :)